# How can i use another model in the same controller? CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp

like i have a posts table, and i build a postscontroller and a Post model to r/w data, but what if i also want r/w data to another table called users? I build another model called user, and how should do to get data from users table in postscontroller?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make this:

```
// Call in Controller's methods to load dynamically model Article and set it to $this->User 
$this->loadModel('User');

// Add this variable as Controller's property and get $this->Post and $this->User accessible
var $uses = array('Post','User');
```

Read more about [Controller::$uses](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3a%24uses) and [Controller::loadModel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aloadModel).

Answer (score -1):

You read the manual under controllers where you will that [`loadModel()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aloadModel) is what you're looking for or you search stack exchange for the answer or even google it.